# Could not load file or assembly 'System.ComponentModel.Annotations, Version=4.2.0.0,

Tags: c#, .net, visual-studio

Added below code

```html
<dependentAssembly>
  <assemblyIdentity name="System.ComponentModel.Annotations" publicKeyToken="b03f5f7f11d50a3a" culture="neutral" />
  <bindingRedirect oldVersion="0.0.0.0-4.2.1.0" newVersion="4.0.0.0" />
</dependentAssembly>
```

this didnt work and also tried below code didnt work

```html
<AutoGenerateBindingRedirects>true</AutoGenerateBindingRedirects>
<GenerateBindingRedirectsOutputType>true</GenerateBindingRedirectsOutputType>
```

Comment: Added below code 
<dependentAssembly>
              <assemblyIdentity name="System.ComponentModel.Annotations" publicKeyToken="b03f5f7f11d50a3a" culture="neutral" />
              <bindingRedirect oldVersion="0.0.0.0-4.2.1.0" newVersion="4.0.0.0" />
            </dependentAssembly> 
    this didnt work and also tried below code didnt work
      <AutoGenerateBindingRedirects>true</AutoGenerateBindingRedirects>
        <GenerateBindingRedirectsOutputType>true</GenerateBindingRedirectsOutputType>

Answer (score 1):

Have you tried NuGet yet?

```bsh
Install-Package System.ComponentModel.Annotations
```

Comment: yes,I have installed using Nuget as well,it didnt work for me

Comment: Install-Package System.ComponentModel.Annotations
Package 'System.ComponentModel.Annotations.4.5.0' already exists in project 'WMQ\Beredning.CPA.Infrastructure'
Time Elapsed: 00:00:04.1950770

Comment: Adding the Nuget Dependency to my project worked for me